# I am trying to put gesture dectector in the alert dialog to navigate to next page but the alert box overflows

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am not using any button in alert dialog, so in **action** how can we prevent the overflow the alert dialog, if am using gesture detector or inkwell to get ontap or onpress function or is there any other method to do it

```
  _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
   showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return UnicornAlertDialog(
          title: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Image.asset('images/done.png'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'Verify',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          content: Text('You have successfully verified your mobile number',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0)),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: <Color>[
              Color(0xDD4a00e0),
              Color(0xFF8e2de2),
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: new GestureDetector(

                onTap:(){
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdRoute()));

                } ,
              ),
            ),

          ]
          );
    });
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `"the overflow the alert dialog"`?

Comment: overflow means the content goes beyond the size of the content since I am using a gesture detector, which is causing the overflow problem

Comment: so if you have any exception on the console, simply post it instead of saying cryptic and mysterious  "the overflow the alert dialog"

Comment: Ok my bad, will keep it in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `overflow error` due to GestureDetector used inside `actions` property of the dialog. If you just want user to tap anywhere on the alertDialog, you can wrap the `AlertDialog` with `GestureDetector`. With this, when user taps anywhere on the dialog, it will navigate them to `thirdRoute`. Working code below:

```
_showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return GestureDetector(
            child: AlertDialog(
                title:
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Image.asset('images/done.png'),
                    ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        'Verify',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                content:
                Text('You have successfully verified your mobile number',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0)),
//              gradient: LinearGradient(
//                colors: <Color>[
//                  Color(0xDD4a00e0),
//                  Color(0xFF8e2de2),
//                ],
//                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
//                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
//              ),
                actions: <Widget>[]
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextScreen()));
            }
          );
        });
  }
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Not only alert dialog but as well as unicornalertdialog can be wrapped in it and the solution works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
      _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return GestureDetector(
        child: UnicornAlertDialog(
            title: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Image.asset('images/done.png'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    'Verify',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            content: Text(
                'You have successfully verified your mobile number',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0)),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: <Color>[
                Color(0xDD4a00e0),
                Color(0xFF8e2de2),
              ],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[ ]),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdRoute()));
        },
      );
    });
   }
```

Unicorn alert dialog is used for background-color decoration, and since you cannot have gradient color in normal alert dialog, I used this.

Answer (score 0):

code snippet

```
_showDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return UnicornAlertDialog(
            title: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () { print("on tap title");},
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/background.jpg'),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'Verify',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            content: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () { print("on tap content");},
              child: Text('You have successfully verified your mobile number',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0)),
            ),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: <Color>[
                Color(0xDD4a00e0),
                Color(0xFF8e2de2),
              ],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[


            ]
        );
      });
}
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class UnicornAlertDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const UnicornAlertDialog({
    Key key,
    @required this.gradient,
    this.title,
    this.titlePadding,
    this.titleTextStyle,
    this.content,
    this.contentPadding = const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 20.0, 24.0, 24.0),
    this.contentTextStyle,
    this.actions,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.elevation,
    this.semanticLabel,
    this.shape,
  })  : assert(contentPadding != null),
        super(key: key);

  final Gradient gradient;
  final Widget title;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry titlePadding;
  final TextStyle titleTextStyle;
  final Widget content;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry contentPadding;
  final TextStyle contentTextStyle;
  final List<Widget> actions;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final double elevation;
  final String semanticLabel;
  final ShapeBorder shape;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations(context));
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final DialogTheme dialogTheme = DialogTheme.of(context);
    final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];
    String label = semanticLabel;

    if (title != null) {
      children.add(Padding(
        padding: titlePadding ?? EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 24.0, 24.0, content == null ? 20.0 : 0.0),
        child: DefaultTextStyle(
          style: titleTextStyle ?? dialogTheme.titleTextStyle ?? theme.textTheme.title,
          child: Semantics(
            child: title,
            namesRoute: true,
            container: true,
          ),
        ),
      ));
    } else {
      switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
        case TargetPlatform.iOS:
          label = semanticLabel;
          break;
        case TargetPlatform.android:
        case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
          label = semanticLabel ?? MaterialLocalizations.of(context)?.alertDialogLabel;
      }
    }

    if (content != null) {
      children.add(Flexible(
        child: Padding(
          padding: contentPadding,
          child: DefaultTextStyle(
            style: contentTextStyle ?? dialogTheme.contentTextStyle ?? theme.textTheme.subhead,
            child: content,
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }

    if (actions != null) {
      children.add(ButtonTheme.bar(
        child: ButtonBar(
          children: actions,
        ),
      ));
    }

    Widget dialogChild = IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: children,
      ),
    );

    if (label != null)
      dialogChild = Semantics(
        namesRoute: true,
        label: label,
        child: dialogChild,
      );

    return Dialog(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      gradient: gradient,
      elevation: elevation,
      shape: shape,
      child: dialogChild,
    );
  }
}

class Dialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const Dialog({
    Key key,
    this.gradient,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.elevation,
    this.insetAnimationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
    this.insetAnimationCurve = Curves.decelerate,
    this.shape,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Color backgroundColor;
  final double elevation;
  final Duration insetAnimationDuration;
  final Curve insetAnimationCurve;
  final ShapeBorder shape;
  final Widget child;
  final Gradient gradient;

  static const RoundedRectangleBorder _defaultDialogShape =
  RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)));
  static const double _defaultElevation = 24.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final DialogTheme dialogTheme = DialogTheme.of(context);
    return AnimatedPadding(
      padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets + const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 24.0),
      duration: insetAnimationDuration,
      curve: insetAnimationCurve,
      child: MediaQuery.removeViewInsets(
        removeLeft: true,
        removeTop: true,
        removeRight: true,
        removeBottom: true,
        context: context,
        child: Center(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 280.0),
            child: Material(
              color: backgroundColor ?? dialogTheme.backgroundColor ?? Theme.of(context).dialogBackgroundColor,
              elevation: elevation ?? dialogTheme.elevation ?? _defaultElevation,
              shape: shape ?? dialogTheme.shape ?? _defaultDialogShape,
              type: MaterialType.card,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: _defaultDialogShape.borderRadius,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: gradient
                  ),
                  child: child,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



_showDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return UnicornAlertDialog(
            title: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () { print("on tap title");},
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/background.jpg'),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'Verify',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            content: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () { print("on tap content");},
              child: Text('You have successfully verified your mobile number',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0)),
            ),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: <Color>[
                Color(0xDD4a00e0),
                Color(0xFF8e2de2),
              ],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[


            ]
        );
      });
}



Future<void> _ackAlert(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Not in stock'),
        content: const Text('This item is no longer available'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
enum ConfirmAction { CANCEL, ACCEPT }
Future<ConfirmAction> _asyncConfirmDialog(BuildContext context) async {
  return showDialog<ConfirmAction>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button for close dialog!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Reset settings?'),
        content: const Text(
            'This will reset your device to its default factory settings.'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: const Text('CANCEL'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(ConfirmAction.CANCEL);
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: const Text('ACCEPT'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(ConfirmAction.ACCEPT);
            },
          )
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}

Future<String> _asyncInputDialog(BuildContext context) async {
  String teamName = '';
  return showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // dialog is dismissible with a tap on the barrier
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Enter current team'),
        content: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
                child: new TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Team Name', hintText: 'eg. Juventus F.C.'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    teamName = value;
                  },
                ))
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(teamName);
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}

enum Departments { Production, Research, Purchasing, Marketing, Accounting }

Future<Departments> _asyncSimpleDialog(BuildContext context) async {
  return await showDialog<Departments>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: const Text('Select Departments '),
          children: <Widget>[
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, Departments.Production);
              },
              child: const Text('Production'),
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, Departments.Research);
              },
              child: const Text('Research'),
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, Departments.Purchasing);
              },
              child: const Text('Purchasing'),
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, Departments.Marketing);
              },
              child: const Text('Marketing'),
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, Departments.Accounting);
              },
              child: const Text('Accounting'),
            )
          ],
        );
      });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Dialog"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _showDialog(context);
              },
              child: const Text("Unicon Dialog"),
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _ackAlert(context);
              },
              child: const Text("Ack Dialog"),
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final ConfirmAction action = await _asyncConfirmDialog(context);
                print("Confirm Action $action" );
              },
              child: const Text("Confirm Dialog"),
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final Departments deptName = await _asyncSimpleDialog(context);
                print("Selected Departement is $deptName");
              },
              child: const Text("Simple dialog"),
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final String currentTeam = await _asyncInputDialog(context);
                print("Current team name is $currentTeam");
              },
              child: const Text("Input Dialog"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp()));
}
```

[image]